# Best way to mask integer as 32-bit?

Tags: php, hex, integer-overflow

I am running a 64-bit installation of PHP, and from my understanding there is not way to specifically declare a variable as a 32 bit `unsigned int`.

Using this code as an example:

```
$test1 = 0x5BE0CD19;
$test2 = 0x3587272B;
$test3 = 0x1F85C98C;
$test4 = 0x428A2F98;
$test5 = 0x61626380;
$test6 = ($test1 + $test2 + $test3 + $test4 + $test5);
```

Gives me the result `0x154da50e8`

Currently I do the following operations to mask variables as 32 bit:

```
$test6 &= (1 << 32) - 1;
```

I get my desired result of: `0x54da50e8`

For performance reasons, I was wondering, is there a better way to do this without having to use `&= (1 << 32) - 1;` for every variable in the event of an overflow?
It gets quite cluttered constantly adding the mask to each variable on a per-calculation basis.

Thanks

Comment: Bitmasking / shifting / subtraction is ridiculously fast. There is likely no 'performance' impact in context. However, consider just using a constant mask: `$test6 &= 0xffffffff` (assumes 64-bit PHP as does the question), which I'd argue is more clear and "avoids" both the shift and subtraction (does PHP fold constants these days?)

Comment: @user2864740 good to know! It just looked a bit clunky when I have several variables that need masking, but I guess i'll have to live with that